# Installing Oracle Database (Apex)

Tags: oracle, database

I have been trying to install Oracle Database 11g Xpress and I followed the instructions [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wb1ZSeOZ18). Everything went fine. In the end, when I try to start the program using:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe start
```

It gives me:

```
[ ok ] Starting oracle-xe (via systemctl): oracle-xe.service.
```

Which is what I need. But I cannot access the "localhost:8080"? any ways to fix that? or maybe I did not install it properly.

Comment: Oracle DB has an ***insanely*** long load time.  It will not have :8080 available immediately.  You will need to wait a while first.

Comment: How long would it take? @ThomasWard

Comment: It's been a while since I used Oracle, it took about 20 minutes for me, once.

Comment: I tried for more than two hours now; and nothing ;/ @ThomasWard